# How to pass a table as parameter to MySqlCommand?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I am creating a method to select the id from any table by passing a search field.

```
private int SelectId(string tabela, string campo, string valor)
{
    int id = 0;

    using (command = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = conn;

        command.Parameters.Add("@tabela", MySqlDbType.).Value = tabela;
        command.Parameters.Add("@campo", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = campo;
        command.Parameters.Add("@valor", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = valor;

        command.CommandText = "SELECT `id` FROM @tabela WHERE @campo=@valor;";

        try
        {
            id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Number + " : " + ex.Message + command.CommandText);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return id;
}
```

But I get an MySqlException about syntax error. When i look at the Exception message, it shows me the query with the quoted table!
How do I pass the table as parameter without quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most databases won't let you specify table or column names via parameters. Parameters are meant to be for *values*. If you really, really need this to be dynamic, you should validate the input (it should be a known table name, with known column names within that table) and then include that in the SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys. Now I have a better understanding about Parameterized SQL.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Jon.  Here is a sample of your code with the table name inserted directly into the script, instead of as a parameter.  Notice that you'll still want to validate the table and column name to **prevent SQL injection**.  I have not included that here, but I have put in comment stubs for you.

```
private int SelectId(string tabela, string campo, string valor)
    {
        int id = 0;

        using (command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = conn;

            command.Parameters.Add("@campo", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = campo;
            command.Parameters.Add("@valor", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = valor;

            // TODO:  Validate table name for parameter 'tabela' to prevent SQL injection
            // TODO:  Validate column name for parameter 'campo' to prevent SQL injection

            command.CommandText = "SELECT `id` FROM " + tabela + " WHERE @campo=@valor;";

            try
            {
                id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Number + " : " + ex.Message + command.CommandText);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return id;
    }
```