# mysql select command in C# with dynamic column names

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a string in C# which has the column names of a table as shown below

```
shown_itemsName = "billno,department,date,subtotal,tea,coffee";
```

I want to display a table in dataGridView with column names that are there in the string (shown_itemsName) but when i write sql query

```
cmdDataBase.CommandText = "select @shown_itemsName from employee.transaction where department = @department AND MONTH(date) = @month_ AND YEAR(date) = @year_";
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shown_itemsName", shown_itemsName);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", this.department.Text);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month_", this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year_", this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Year);
```

I get a table with only 1 column and 4 rows with the cell value as billno,department,date,subtotal,tea,coffee and the heading of that column also the same string.
Whereas I should be getting 6 columns and 4 rows as the result with the "," separated substrings as the column names

Comment: Read this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386093/how-to-pass-a-table-as-parameter-to-mysqlcommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add new columns with parameters. If it is dynamic you don't have a choice but writing your query every time and execute a CommandType.Text command on it.

For **every** request, you must:

```
cmdDataBase.CommandText = "select " + shown_itemsName + " from employee.transaction where department = @department AND MONTH(date) = @month_ AND YEAR(date) = @year_";

cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", this.department.Text);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month_", this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year_", this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Year);

using(var reader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader()) {
    while(reader.Read()) {
        // ...
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: string shown_itemsName is updated every time user selects department and date . So i want to use that department and date as the input to select command .

Comment: yes so you should build manually the sql query and execute a text command on it. You cannot use stored procedure or prepared statement. I've edited the answer to try to make it clearer

Comment: i didnt refresh the page and wrote that comment but now i have deleted the comment after seeing your answer

Comment: I dont know how to say thank you.It worked exactly like i wanted it to. I was stuck on this thing for 4 to 5 hrs.Thank you so much tafia

Comment: thnx for telling i didnt knew i had to that also